# Voice editing for anime video games

Tags: editing

I'm new to voicing video games and was wondering how the editing process goes. How much editing does the voice actor do?
Thanks,
Natalya

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are recording the VO yourself and are sending the files to the game developers/audio editors. You do as much editing as you like, but generally you're not expected to do your own editing.

What would be appreciated: At the most basic level: remove unnecessary silence before and after the VO (can be very rough edits, just so that the file starts within a second of the beginning and stops not much longer after the end). leave breaths in - they might be appreciated depending on context.

If you deliver 3 takes to give them choices (seems very common; check with developer what they prefer) decide whether to leave them in 1 audio file (ok for short bits) or 3 separate files. name them FileName_take1 to ~3 or sg similar. But once you decide, stick to it for the same developer so they know what to expect. If you feel strongly about your takes, you can separate them in to "best take" and "alt takes" (separate folders). again, that's optional as the developer will make their own decisions.

Btw: proper file naming is very important. If you get a list/script with suggested file names, use those. If it's just one file (like an ad copy) that they'd cut up, name it after the project + take numbers. If you get a list of sentences/words without file names, I suggest to put them in a spread sheet program and number them - use the numbers as file names + send the list to developer (and suggest they do that next time). but that's all bonus stuff you'd be doing. You can also send all the lines in one long audio file and let them cut it up. again, best to discuss with the developers. ask them what they'd like for delivery. No need to suggest to do services that you're not being paid for (unless you think it gives you an edge over the competition).

For almost automatic file naming, try Voxover: http://www.audiofile-engineering.com/voxover/  (pricy and only worth it if you a lot of VO recordings and want to save yourself the hassle of manual file naming; used in commercial studios. not a requirement for self-recording VO artists)

cleaning up mouth clicks and other sounds is optional, certainly not expected. Most of the voice over I received was not cleaned up and I did not expect it to be. One reason: developer will select the preferred take and focus their efforts on cleaning that one up. no need to waste time on cleaning up unused takes.

however, do make sure that there is no or minimal background noise (like cars driving by; sounds from the house…) but that's part of the recording anyways. just listen to your VO for such noise and rerecord if you find any that can't be cleaned up with a simple high pass filter.

No need to do any EQing or compression or the like, unless you know exactly what you're doing and it is part of your signature sound. Leave that to the editors because it gives them more freedom to adjust to their needs.

my qualifications: While I'm mainly a composer these days, I recorded, produced + edited VO for over 30 games (amongst other things) - main client: Leapfrog.

Comment: Interestingly, a buddy of mine is an art guy over at 1stPlayable.  Also, welcome to the site.

Comment: Hi AJ. Thanks for the welcome. Nice coincidence :-) they're a very cool company. I almost got to work on a Leapfrog game with them. It sadly got cancelled mid project due to technical difficulties with the hardware. I'd love to work with them for real.

Answer (score 0):

None, the recording engineer and the sound editors do all the editing.  The voice actor just does performances.